# Jquery Toggle Hide / Show Nav Element

Tags: javascript, jquery

After some great help from Josh Mein with a Javascript Hide/Show menu, the menu is working 100%, though I would like it when the page loads, that the menu is in it's "Hide state". Here is the jsFiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/8y7Sr/3/  ...when you load the page, the menu is showing and when you clicking on "Toggle Menu", it will HIDE the nav. That's perfect BUT How can I make it so that when you load the page, the menu is in it's hide state already and when you click on "Toggle Menu", the nav slides up? Josh mentioned that, to get this right, I must comment `$("#stickyfooter").show();` out and add `class="show_hide"` to the div ID stickyfooter . I've been fiddling around but I can't seem to get it working. I've most likely done something wrong but can anyone clarify what Josh mean't? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: start with: $("#stickyfooter").hide(); $("#sticky_footer_title ").css({'bottom':0}); could you help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a minimal change to your existing code just programmatically trigger your existing click event immediately:

```
$('.show_hide').click(function(){
   // your existing function code here

}).click();    // <---- add this bit
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/8y7Sr/8/

Alternatively, remove the first line of code:

```
$("#stickyfooter").show();        // <--- delete this line
```

Change the `#sticky_footer_title` class to have:

```
bottom: 0px;
```

And change the `#stickyfooter` class to have:

```
display: none;
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/8y7Sr/11/

(As an aside, having both an id and a class called "stickyfooter" is kind of confusing. To me it would make more sense if the containing div had `id="stickyfootercontainer"` instead of `class="stickyfooter"`.)

Comment: Excellent! I've tried both your solutions and they work! Though I have opted to go for the alternative solution :) I agree it is slightly confusing (especially going back to that code after a long time) and I have indeed followed your suggestion of changing it to id="stickyfootercontainer" ... well spotted! Thank you tons for helping me out here. Hope this helps others!!

Comment: ... as much as I thought this had to do with the javascript part, I should have paid more attention to the CSS. It's a learning curve!!

Answer (score 0):

A bit more simplified

### **HTML**

```
<div class="stickyfooter">
    <div id="sticky_footer_title">
        <a href="#">Toggle Menu &#x25BC;</a>
    </div>
    <div id="stickyfooter">
        <ul id="footer_menu">
            <li class="imgmenu"><a href="#"></a></li>
            <li><a href="#intro">Intro</a></li>
            <li><a href="#photos">Photos</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

### **JAVASCRIPT**

```
var showMenu = $("#stickyfooter");
var menuTrigger = $("#sticky_footer_title");

menuTrigger.find("a").toggle(
    function() {
        $(this).parent().animate({ bottom: '0px' }, "slow");
        showMenu.slideToggle("slow");
    },
    function() {
        $(this).parent().animate({ bottom: '40px' }, "slow");
        showMenu.slideToggle("slow");
    }
);
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/7YMPK/